# How can I use cloudfront to have images hosted by prismic come from my own domain?

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, prismic.io

I am using prismic headless CMS which hosts images on its own cdn.

Images have a name that is not SEO friendly and they are hosted on an external domain.

Prismic does not offer a way to set up a custom domain for images.

Our website also uses cloudfront which caches pages.

Is there a way to parse html content and rewrite image urls so that they come from our own domain?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: URLs are not content and do not play a part in seo. Note: General SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: well, I'm not asking for an advice on SEO, I'm asking for a technical solution. and although there are people who think like you, there are some who saw a large traffic increase after hosting their images on the own website. Not saying I'm right, but I want to try it. So you're just not answering my question

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer. Since you say you are not asking for seo advice. I removed the seo tag for you.